# How would I get my image to occupy the whole image view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an image view with constraints set up, and the image that I load in (from a URL) doesn't fill the whole image view for some reason. I included a picture of the one in question followed by the detail view of the same 'post'. The same code is used for both. In the detail view (one that appears correctly), I set the post image in during viewdidload, and it's a standalone view. The one that loads in wonky is a table view cell with a custom class, and the image is set in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. I do resize the image before I send it to Back4App with parse to 500x500, and the image views are both set to clip to bounds and aspect fit. the uiimageview constraints are exactly the same, with horizontal alignment of zero, a fixed width and height, and constraints for all four sides (8 away from nearest neighbors)

here are code snippets for how both of them are done:

pink background:

```
- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PostCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PostCell"];
    Post *post = self.posts[indexPath.row];
    
    PFUser *user = post.author;
    [user fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        cell.usernameLabel.text = post.author.username;
    }];
    cell.titleLabel.text = post.caption;
    cell.isLiked = NO;
    
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:post.image.url];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL];
    
    
    return cell;
}
```

one that loads correctly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    PFUser *user = self.post.author;
    [user fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        self.usernameTextLabel.text = self.post.author.username;
    }];
    self.titleTextLabel.text = self.post.caption;
    self.descriptionTextLabel.text = self.post.bodyText;
    NSURL *postImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.post.image.url];
    [self.postImageView setImageWithURL:postImageURL];'''
    
}
```

Any tips? There may be some basics that I don't have a handle on - i took a crash course basically and I've only been at this for about 3 weeks so I don't understand a lot of this as deeply as I wish I did.

[I've set the background color to pink so you could see the image size vs image view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ3Yl.png)

[one that loads correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjzsa.jpg)

***side note: i literally can't figure out how to do blocks of code correctly??? i'm following what it says lol***

Comment: Its not clear how your "PostCell" table view cell is configured.  You'd typically use `[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit]` to scale an image (preserving aspect ratio) to fit the bounds of the imageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accidentally using the default imageView that the cell comes with instead of my own outlet to my new image view.

Answer (score 0):

Check following points

1. Debug the frame size of the ImageView that it is correct which you supplied.
2. Set following to the ImageView

   ```
     [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL];
     cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
     [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
   ```

Comment: thanks for commenting, but I figured it out!